# InnerHTML = "string" not modifying shown page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a little Javascript toy that, in part, will have cells in a table cycle between 3 images each time it's clicked on. I'm trying to achieve this by setting the InnerHTML of a `<div>` inside the otherwise empty `<td>`, but the contents of the cell aren't visibly updating.

Here's my code in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Mirror Game</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/mirrors.css" /> 
</head>
<body>
<table id="gameTable">
  <tr id="rowA">
    <td id="A1"></td>
    <!-- I'll spare you the whole, currently empty table -->
  </tr>
  <tr id="rowB">
    <td id="B1"></td>
    <td><div id="B2"><img src="../images/mirrors/blank.png" /></div></td>
    <td id="B3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="links">
<a href="../index.html">Click here to return to the index!</a><br />
<script src="../js/mirrors.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

(the CSS just makes the cells 50*50 with a border so I know where I'm clicking)

And in JS:

```
var B2state = 0;
var B2image = "blank";
document.getElementById("B2").addEventListener("click", function() { 
    console.log(B2state); //debug
    ++B2state;
    console.log(B2state); //debug
    if (B2state > 2 || B2state < 0) { //keeps state looping around from 0-2
        B2state = 0;
    }
    console.log(B2state); //debug
    switch (B2state) {
        case 0: B2image = "blank"; break;
        case 1: B2image = "slash"; break;
        case 2: B2image = "backslash"; break;
        default: B2image = "blank"; alert("state out of bounds"); break; //should never happen, hence why i have it tell me if so
    }
    console.log(B2image); //debug
    document.getElementById("B2").InnerHTML = "<img src=\"../images/mirrors/" + B2image + ".png\" />";
    console.log(document.getElementById("B2").InnerHTML); //debug
}, false);
```

According to the console logs, everything is working as it should. The state is incrementing/looping around, the "image" string is changing to what it should be, and most notably, the InnerHTML is printing to the console as an `<img>` with the right src. However, nothing on the page changes.

Searching for solutions only shows issues where people have loaded the script before what they're trying to change with InnerHTML, which I've made sure to avoid here.

Comment: To be blunt, I'm a total novice scrabbling together what I can from what little knowledge I've picked up. This is just something to keep me occupied when I'm bored, I'm not really invested enough to learn something new for it. I'm just curious why it won't work when all logic seems to dictate that it should.

Comment: InnerHTML -> innerHTML

Comment: jQuery is dying a slow death anyway. While still useful, vanilla js is definitely fine for this - nevermind the problem appears to be a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("B2").innerHTML = "<img src=\"../images/mirrors/" + B2image + ".png\" />";
```

You have innerHTML with capital i (InnerHTML). 
If it still doesnt work, check this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp) to learn how to add html elements

Comment: Gosh darn it, I thought I checked the capitalisation against a resource, but I must have been mistaken. Thanks to you and everyone else who suggested the same thing, I'll accept this answer as soon as I'm able.